# reload a part of JSP page without refreshing the whole page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am working on combination of jsp and servlets. I have to reload a specific part of jsp page ( maybe table, div or section ) when servlet updates the value in db, without refreshing the entire page.

I am not a pro jQuery user, but can understand it as beginner.

Comment: You should use AJAX to achieve this. jQuery does support this.

Comment: Ajax will do for you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your table, div or section an id (aaa in example) and try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<button onclick="jQuery('#aaa').load(' #aaa');">Reload</button>
<div id="aaa"><%=new java.util.Date().toString()%></div>
```

Comment: Important is the whitespace before the #aaa

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ajax`, which browser will support default as simple too.

You can also use `DWR(Direct Web Remoting)`, but it require to add some additional configuration in web.xml and add jar.